# Can an object move faster than light in an accelerated frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, faster-than-light

In an accelerated frame attached to an accelerating rocket the Lorentz contraction of the rest frame is steadily increasing, which means that distant galaxies are getting closer and closer. Does this mean that the galaxies are moving faster than light (towards the rocket) in the accelerated frame?

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted...he's asking about "The Rindler Observer"....who sees a horizon afaik. BTW: instead of the awkward _accelerating frame attached to an accelerating rocket_, "Does a Rindler Observer see distance galaxies moving FTL?"

Comment: In whatever reference frame you consider the velocity of a material point is less or equal to $c$.

Comment: What do you count as a "frame"?    For example, is it required to contain a future-directed timelike vector?

Comment: @WillO Are you asking me or Valter Moretti?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh :  I was asking you.

Comment: @WillO I have no idea what a future-directed timelike vector is. By "frame" I mean "frame of reference" which I think is equivalent to a lattice of clocks and rods.

Answer (score 7):

When you move from one inertial frame to another, or, to put it another way, when you are in an accelerating reference frame, the coordinates of objects can indeed move faster than c. If you are standing so that the Sun is directly to your right, and you swivel round so the Sun is directly to your left, in your accelerating frame of reference the Sun has moved around you faster than the value of c.

If you accelerate from rest in a straight line, distances in your original rest frame will be shortened as a consequence of length contraction, so that an object sufficiently far away will appear to be moving towards you faster than c. However, the light from that distant object will also seem to be approaching you faster than c, so the distant object is still not 'really' moving faster than light- the effect is just an artefact of your continually changing reference frame. See, for example, https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/speed_of_light.html

Comment: It sounds like an accelerated frame of reference attached to an accelerating rocket is not one frame but an infinite number of frames. And therefore the change in coordinates of a distant galaxy, or nearby star, for that matter, is not real movement. Does that mean an accelerated frame of reference is not frame of reference?

Comment: A reference frame is a set of dimensions we use to note the positions of events, so you can use a frame with an accelerating origin if you want to. However, if you do, then you have to accept that the usual formulas of physics which assume inertial reference frames won't apply in your accelerating frame.

Comment: Does that imply that inertial reference frames are the default in relativity? So much so that relativists sometimes just say "reference frame" when they really mean "inertial reference frame"? For example, I think I've heard, "The speed of light is the same regardless which frame of reference it is measured in" or "the same for all observers" i.e. nonaccelerating observers.

Comment: But I think you mean swivel the earth around, right? Swiveling your body around won't move the sun from east to west. Also, are you saying that a material object with mass going faster than c is allowed, but that object going faster than light in a vacuum is not?

Comment: Yes to your point about frames- when people mention reference frames in SR they ought to say inertial reference frame, but that's such a mouthful- some people just say frame.

Comment: To your other point, no object can move between two points faster than light can. If you use the conventional scheme for quantifying distances and time (eg inertial reference frames) then no massive object can move faster than c. If you use accelerating reference frames, then the speed of light will no longer take the normal value c, and the speed of massive objects can exceed the value c, but the speed of massive objects cannot exceed whatever the speed of light is in such a frame.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the galaxies are moving faster than light (towards the rocket) in the accelerated frame?

In a coordinate-independent sense nothing with mass can ever move faster than light. However, in non-inertial frames it is possible for things with mass to move faster than c. In such frames the speed of light is not restricted to c, so moving faster than light and moving faster than c are not the same.

Comment: +1 And that's interesting that c and light in a vacuum are not the same in a non-inertial frame. That's not common knowledge at all.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh yes, it isn’t exactly hidden, but it is rarely taught. If you look at the wording of the second postulate, eg here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity it says “As measured in any **inertial** frame of reference, light is always propagated in empty space with a definite velocity c” (emphasis added). So the fact that it is not a rule for non inertial frames is implied, but very quietly